# How the same php code runs on live server but not on xampp localhost?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, server

on local . [image: on server]Here is my code that I am trying to run on my localhost xampp but its not showing the appropriate result and no errors. But at the same time the same code runs on live server completely fine. May i know the reason why I am facing this issue.
Here is my code for that page.

```
<?php include 'blocks/headerInc.php' ; ?>
<?php include 'blocks/leftnavInc.php' ; ?>  
<?php /*?><div class="panel panel-primary" style="display:none;">
    <div class="panel-heading">Questionnaire Summary</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 noPadding">
            <?php for($c =1 ; $c<=20 ; $c++){?>
                <a href="#<?php echo $c; ?>info" id="<?php echo $c; ?>" class="cercleAns"><?php echo $c; ?></a>
            <?php } ?>    
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><?php */?>
<?php
$attemptCount   =   '';
$questionCounter=   '';
$moduleQuestions=   '';
$attempt        =   '';

$uid    =   $_SESSION['session_user_id'];
if(isset($_REQUEST['moduleId']) && $_REQUEST['moduleId']!='')
    {
        $moduleId=$fnc->decode(trim($_REQUEST['moduleId']));
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['chapterId']) && $_REQUEST['chapterId']!='')
  {
    $chapterId=$fnc->decode(trim($_REQUEST['chapterId']));
  }

//Count quetsion modules and compare with modules master question counter start here
$questionCounter    =   $fnc->countChapterQuestions($chapterId) ;   
$moduleQuestions    =   $db->idToField("tbl_studymaterials", "total_questions", $chapterId) ;
$duration           =   $db->idToField("tbl_studymaterials", "duration", $chapterId) ;
if($questionCounter <  $moduleQuestions)
{
    echo "<script>window.location.href='thankYou_chapter.php?type=".$fnc->encode('mismatch')."&moduleId=".$fnc->encode($moduleId)."&chapterId=".$fnc->encode($chapterId)."'</script>";
    die;
}
//Count quetsion modules and compare with modules master question counter ends here
/*$counter      =   $fnc->restrictModule($uid, $moduleId);  
if($counter > 0)
{
    echo "<script>window.location.href='thankYou.php?type=".$fnc->encode('att')."'</script>";
    die;    
}*/

?>
<?php
$pageWasRefreshed = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] === 'max-age=0'; 
if($pageWasRefreshed ) {
  echo "<script>window.location.href='dashboard.php'</script>";die;
} else {
    $attemptCount   =   $fnc->userAttempt($uid, $moduleId); 
  echo '<input name="" type="button"  value="Please do not refresh the page" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">';
}
?>


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 page-right">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Questionnaire Details



          <div class="lead" style="width:30%; text-align:right; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;" id="clock"><?php echo $duration ; ?>:00</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6 noPadding">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="Module" class="control-label">Chapter:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8"> <strong><?php echo $db->idToField("tbl_studymaterials", "title", $chapterId) ; ?></strong> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 noPadding">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="Chapter" class="control-label">Total Marks <?php //echo $total_marks; ?></label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8"> 
<?php
$total_marks    =   $db->idToField("tbl_studymaterials", "total_marks", $chapterId); 
//$totalMarks       =   $totalQuestions * 5;
?>
              <strong><?php //echo $totalQuestions ; ?> : <?php echo $total_marks ; ?></strong> </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
            <div class="col-md-6 noPadding">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="Marks" class="control-label">Total Marks:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8"> <strong>30x5 = 150</strong> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 noPadding">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="Time" class="control-label">Time Limit:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8"> <strong>40 min.</strong> </div>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>






  <form id="target" method="post" action="processQuiz_chapter.php">
      <div class="panel panel-primary" style="">
        <ul class="list-group">



<?php
echo '<input type="hidden" name="time_spend" value="$duration" id="time_spend">';
if(isset($_REQUEST['moduleId']) && $_REQUEST['moduleId']!='')
    {
        $moduleId=$fnc->decode(trim($_REQUEST['moduleId']));
        if(!is_numeric($moduleId))
        {
            header("Location:index.php");   
        }
    }

if(isset($_REQUEST['chapterId']) && $_REQUEST['chapterId']!='')
  {
    $chapterId=$fnc->decode(trim($_REQUEST['chapterId']));
    if(!is_numeric($chapterId))
    {
      header("Location:index.php"); 
    }
  }


$i              =   0;
$no             =   1;
$sectionOne     =   1 ;
$sectionTwo     =   1 ;
$sectionThree   =   1 ;

$sq =$db->query("select * from (select * from tbl_question_chapter order by rand()) as t WHERE chapter = $chapterId and module_id=$moduleId order by section ASC" );

//$sq =$db->query("SELECT id, question, marks, unit from tbl_question WHERE module_id = $moduleId ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sq))
{

?>          


 <?php if($sectionOne <= 10 && $row['section'] == 1) {?>  

          <li class="list-group-item active">
            <div class="radio noMargin" id="<?php echo $sectionOne ; ?>info"><?php echo $no ; ?> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></div><div class="question"><?php echo $row['question'] ; ?></div>
<div style="float:right; margin-top:-20px;">Marks:<?php echo $row['marks'] ; ?></div></li>
<?php          
echo '<input type="hidden" name="question[]" id="questionId" value="'.$row['id'].'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="attempt" value="'.$attemptCount.'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="moduleId" value="'.$moduleId.'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="chapterId" value="'.$chapterId.'">';

$questionId     =   $row['id'] ;  

$sqO =$db->query("SELECT id, options from  tbl_chapter_options WHERE question_id = ".$questionId."");
while($rowO=mysql_fetch_array($sqO))
{
?>  
    <li class="list-group-item wrp_radio">
      <div class="radio noMargin">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" class="checkedInfo" alt="<?php echo $no ; ?>"  name="optionAns<?php echo $i ; ?>"  value="<?php echo $rowO['id'] ; ?>">
          <?php echo $rowO['options'] ; ?></label>
      </div>
    </li>
<?php } ?> 


   <li class="list-group-item wrp_radio">
      <div class="radio noMargin">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" class="checkedInfo" alt="<?php echo $no ; ?>" accesskey="notAttempt" checked name="optionAns<?php echo $i ; ?>"  value="NA">
          <p style="color:red;">I am not Attempting this question</p></label>
      </div>
    </li>



<li class="list-group-item">
<div class="wrp_review">
      <div class="radio noMargin  bg-danger">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkedInfo" alt="<?php echo $no ; ?>" accesskey="revision" name="optionAnss<?php echo $i ; ?>"  id="optionAns<?php echo $no  ; ?>" value="NA">
          Revision</label>
      </div>
      </div>
    </li>                
        </ul>        
<?php $i++;$no++; ?>
<?php $sectionOne++;} ?>


<?php if($sectionTwo <= 5 && $row['section'] == 2) {?>         
          <li class="list-group-item active">
            <div class="radio noMargin"  id="<?php echo $no ; ?>info"><?php echo $no ; ?> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></div><div class="question"><?php echo $row['question'];?></div>
          <div style="float:right; margin-top:-20px;">Marks:<?php echo $row['marks'] ; ?></div></li>
<?php          
echo '<input type="hidden" name="question[]" id="questionId" value="'.$row['id'].'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="attempt" value="'.$attemptCount.'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="moduleId" value="'.$moduleId.'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="chapterId" value="'.$chapterId.'">';

$questionId     =   $row['id'] ;  

$sqO =$db->query("SELECT id, options from  tbl_chapter_options WHERE question_id = ".$questionId."");
while($rowO=mysql_fetch_array($sqO))
{
?>  
    <li class="list-group-item wrp_radio">
      <div class="radio noMargin">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" class="checkedInfo" alt="<?php echo $no ; ?>" name="optionAns<?php echo $i ; ?>" value="<?php echo $rowO['id'] ; ?>">
          <?php echo $rowO['options'] ; ?></label>
      </div>
    </li>
<?php } ?>   

   <li class="list-group-item wrp_radio">
      <div class="radio noMargin">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" class="checkedInfo" alt="<?php echo $no ; ?>" accesskey="notAttempt" checked name="optionAns<?php echo $i ; ?>" id="optionAns<?php echo $i ; ?>" value="NA">
          <p style="color:red;">I am not Attempting this question</p></label>
      </div>
    </li> 

<li class="list-group-item" >
<div class="wrp_review">
      <div class="radio noMargin bg-danger">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkedInfo" alt="<?php echo $no ; ?>" accesskey="revision" name="optionAnss<?php echo $i ; ?>"  id="optionAns<?php echo $no  ; ?>" value="NA">
          Revision</label>
      </div>
      </div>
    </li>                

        </ul>        
<?php $i++;$no++; ?>
<?php $sectionTwo++;} ?>


<?php if($sectionThree <= 5 && $row['section'] == 3) {?>         
          <li class="list-group-item active">
            <div class="radio noMargin"  id="<?php echo $no ; ?>info"><?php echo $no ; ?> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></div><div class="question"><?php echo $row['question'] ; ?></div>
          <div style="float:right; margin-top:-20px;">Marks:<?php echo $row['marks'] ; ?></div></li>
<?php          
echo '<input type="hidden" name="question[]" id="questionId" value="'.$row['id'].'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="attempt" value="'.$attemptCount.'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="moduleId" value="'.$moduleId.'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="chapterId" value="'.$chapterId.'">';

$questionId     =   $row['id'] ;  

$sqO =$db->query("SELECT id, options from  tbl_chapter_options WHERE question_id = ".$questionId."");
while($rowO=mysql_fetch_array($sqO))
{
?>  
    <li class="list-group-item wrp_radio">
      <div class="radio noMargin">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" class="checkedInfo" alt="<?php echo $no ; ?>" name="optionAns<?php echo $i ; ?>" value="<?php echo $rowO['id'] ; ?>">
          <?php echo $rowO['options'] ; ?></label>
      </div>
    </li>
<?php } ?>   

   <li class="list-group-item wrp_radio">
      <div class="radio noMargin">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" class="checkedInfo" alt="<?php echo $no ; ?>" accesskey="notAttempt" checked name="optionAns<?php echo $i ; ?>" id="optionAns<?php echo $i ; ?>" value="NA">
          <p style="color:red;">I am not Attempting this question</p></label>
      </div>
    </li>   

<li class="list-group-item">
<div class="wrp_review">
      <div class="radio noMargin bg-danger">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkedInfo" alt="<?php echo $no ; ?>" accesskey="revision" name="optionAnss<?php echo $i ; ?>"  id="optionAns<?php echo $no  ; ?>" value="NA">
          Revision</label>
      </div>
      </div>
    </li>                


        </ul>        
<?php $i++;$no++; ?>
<?php $sectionThree++;} ?>

<?php



} ?>        

      </div>  
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-body">   
      <div class="col-md-12 noPadding text-center">
 <?php echo '<input type="hidden" name="submitQuiz" value="submit" >';     ?>
        <button type="submit" style="display:none;"  name="submitQuiz" value="submit" class="btn btn-success wrp_submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i> Submit</button>
        <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success wrp_submit_togle"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i> Submit</button>

      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
</form>   


    </div>
    <!--/.sidebar-offcanvas-->
  </div>
</div>


<div class="sideToolBar" >
      <div id="CollapsBut" class="CollapsSB"><span id="CollapsSaa" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></div>
      <div class="clearfix sideToolBax">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Questionnaire Details

        </div>
        <div class="panel-body left">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12 noPadding marginBottom10">
                <strong>Chapter:</strong> <?php echo $db->idToField("tbl_studymaterials", "title", $chapterId) ; ?>
            </div>            
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12 noPadding marginBottom10">
                <strong>Total Marks:</strong> <?php echo $total_marks ; ?>
            </div>            
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">            
            <div class="col-xs-12 noPadding marginBottom10">
                 <div class="lead" style="width:100%; float:left; text-align:left; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;" id="clock1"><?php echo $duration ; ?>:00</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 noPadding">
                <div class="marginBottom10"><strong>Click on numbers to Answer:</strong></div>

                 <?php for($c =1 ; $c<=20 ; $c++){?>
                <a href="#<?php echo $c; ?>info" id="<?php echo $c; ?>" class="cercleAns"><?php echo $c; ?></a>
            <?php } ?> 
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      </div>
    </div>




<?php include 'blocks/footerInc.php' ; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Turn on Bootstrap
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

  // 15 days from now!
  function get15dayFromNow() {    return new Date(new Date().valueOf() + <?php echo $duration ; ?> * 60 * 1000);
  }

   var $time_spend = $('#time_spend');
  $time_spend.countdown(get15dayFromNow(), function(event) {
    $(this).val(event.strftime('%M:%S'));
  });

  var $clock = $('#clock, #clock1');
  $clock.countdown(get15dayFromNow(), function(event) {
    $(this).html('Time Left :   '+'00:'+event.strftime('%M:%S'));

    var counterVal  =   $("#clock").text();
    if((counterVal   == '00:00') || (counterVal   == '00:00:00'))
    { 
        submitForm(); 
    }


  });

function submitForm()
{
    document.getElementById("target").submit();
}

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".sideToolBax").hide();
  $("#CollapsBut").click(function() {
      $(".sideToolBax").toggle("slide");
      $("#CollapsSaa").toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-left glyphicon-chevron-right');

  })
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  //$(document).ready(function(){
$('.wrp_review').hide();
$('.wrp_radio input[type="radio"]').click(function(){

if($(this).val()=="NA"){
  $(this).closest('ul').find('.wrp_review').hide();

  $(this).closest('ul').find('.wrp_review input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
}else{
  $(this).closest('ul').find('.wrp_review').show();  
}

});





  //});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).on('click', '.wrp_submit_togle', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
      $(".sideToolBax").show('fast');
      $("#CollapsSaa").toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-left glyphicon-chevron-right');
      //$('.wrp_submit').trigger('click');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.wrp_submit').trigger('click');
      }, 1000);
     return false;

  });
  $(document).on('click', '.wrp_submit', function(){
     return confirm('Do you want to submit the Quiz...');

  });

</script>
```

Comment: try this URL

http://localhost/phpmyadmin/   if this will not open means you did not start the server.

Comment: `not showing the appropriate result and no errors` may we know how the results differ?

Comment: Actually this is a page for a mock online test and the questions are displayed wth options on live server with time limit only but not on the localhost. Rest of the pages of application are working fine but only the questions page is not loading.  @JaromandaX

Comment: Localhost is working fine. Because I can load all other page of the apllication.

Comment: when you say `no errors` - that means no errors in the browser developer tools console, right

Comment: ok, so what DO you see on localhost instead of the "questions with time limits" - a rare occasion where a screen shot of working and non-working page may actually help with your vague description of the problem

Comment: I see lots of what I assume to be jQuery code, but nowhere is jQuery being loaded - however, this would produce errors in the browser console, and yet you say you get no errors

Comment: i am a bit new to php. can u please let me know about how to use the browser developer tools console ?? and additionally how to send screenshot to you. If possible please invite for a chat @JaromandaX

Comment: browser developer tools has nothing to do with PHP - anyway, F12 in most browsers brings up developer tools, look for console, reload the page, see what errors may occur - and no, I don't want screenshots

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148466/discussion-between-anand-shankar-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: why is your html block commented? <code> <?php /* ... */?> </code> .

Comment: at which line?? @taha

Comment: starting right after the includes (3rd line I guess)

Comment: @taha Yeah I got it . there was some file inclusion issue. Thanks a ton for the help..

Comment: @JaromandaX Some file inclusion issue.. thanks a ton for your valuable time

Comment: what matters is that you got it :) happy coding